# Getting data from the database and render it on to the table in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am new to the world of backbone.js . I want to communicate with the server using backbone.js and render the employee details on to the table .I am getting the data from the server using following code:

```
    var EmployeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    url:"http://localhost:4000/get/employee",
     parse : function(res) 
     {
         console.log('response inside parse' + res);
        return res;
     }

});

var employee = new EmployeeCollection();
employee.fetch();
```

In log statement i am getting :`response inside parse[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

But i don't know what next. How to retrieve the data from the object i am getting and render it on to the table . Do anyone have suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume you have a table in your HTML page with `id="employee"` and you have defined a `template` corresponding to a row in the table. For simplicity, we asssume employee row just has `firstname` and `lastname`:

```
<table id="employee">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Firstname</td><td>Lastname</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/template" id="employee-template">
    <td><%= firstname %></td><td><%= lastname %></td>
</script>​
```

You need two `views` one to render the table, and one to render each row in the table. They may look like:

```
//a (table) view to render the list of employees
var employee_list_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#employee'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind("add", this.render, this);
    },

    //this creates new rows in the table for each model in the collection
    render: function() {
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(data) {
            this.$el.append(new employee_view({
                model: data
            }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

//a (row) view to render each employee
var employee_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: _.template($("#employee-template").html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

After you fetch the collection from the server, the items are stored within the collection. You can view the retrieved data using the following code. On success we create a new employee list (table in this case) and pass the employee collection.

```
var employee = new EmployeeCollection();

employee.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(employee.toJSON());
        new employee_list_view({collection: employee}).render();
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Failed to fetch!');
    }
});
```

Note: its recommended to use the success/fail callbacks.

Take a look at this [working version on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVxwz/1/)

Comment: `_.each(this.collection.models, ...` might be nicer as [`this.collection.each(...)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods). And don't you want to `this.$('tbody').append(...)` to add the `employee_view`s?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Guess, I am learning lots of stuff myself participating in the Q/A. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can get much more information if you use `console.log` in this way `console.log('response inside parse', res);`. `res` won't be converted to string, but it will be displayed as a JavaScript object with all its properties and values. Then, check the backbone.js docs [Collection.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) and read what the `res` is in this context and what this method should return.

Probably next step would be to create a View which renders a table using some template and data from your collection.